# PHP implode() replacing all array values with "array"

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

As part of MySQL SELECT statement I'm trying to dynamically query the database.

Current code:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`="assignment" AND `TABLE_NAME`=:table AND `COLUMN_NAME` != :column1 AND `COLUMN_NAME` != :column2;');
  $criteria = [
    'table' => $_GET['section'],
    'column1' => 'jobid',
    'column2' => 'catid'
  ];
  $stmt->execute($criteria);

  $arr = array();

  echo '<form method="POST">';
  foreach ($stmt as $row){
    echo '<label>'.ucwords($row['COLUMN_NAME']).':</label>
    <input type="text" name="'.$row['COLUMN_NAME'].'"/><p>';
    $arr[] = $row;
  }
  echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
      </form>';

  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    echo $query = implode(',', $arr);
```

I've got it working just fine using $_POST values but for some reason it outputs:

```
Array,Array,Array,Array,Array
```

even though the var_dump() of $arr is:

```
    0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'COLUMN_NAME' => string 'title' (length=5)
      0 => string 'title' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'COLUMN_NAME' => string 'salary' (length=6)
      0 => string 'salary' (length=6)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'COLUMN_NAME' => string 'location' (length=8)
      0 => string 'location' (length=8)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'COLUMN_NAME' => string 'description' (length=11)
      0 => string 'description' (length=11)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'COLUMN_NAME' => string 'category' (length=8)
      0 => string 'category' (length=8)
```

Comment: implode() does not work on multidimensional arrays.

Comment: your var_dump shows that $arr is an array of arrays.  is that what you want?

Comment: Is that pseudo code because I can see a number of reasons it should not get past the first query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `implode` function doesn't work the way that you want with an array of arrays. It takes the arrays in `$arr` and makes them into the string 'Array'. You can loop through the array and implode that way, for example,

```
$list = '';
foreach ($arr as $inner) {
    $list .= $inner['COLUMN_NAME'].',';
}
$list = rtrim($list,',');
```

Comment: Works great but repeats the elements and I can't figure it out:
title,titlesalary,salarylocation,locationdescription,descriptioncategory,category

Comment: It's because `'COLUMN_NAME'` has the same value as `0`. Hang on & I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been staring at it for hours